# Unable to install anything on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, dependencies

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` isn't working. I tried many solved answers, but they all result in the below error messages:

```
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text depends on plymouth (= 0.9.2-3ubuntu13.2); however:   
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (-- configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:   
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.23); however:  
  Package bluez is not configured yet.  

dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 apache2   
 plymouth   
 lm-sensors   
 unattended-upgrades   
 bluez   
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo   
 plymouth-label   
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text   
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Comment: What did you do to get into this situation?

Comment: The laptop turned off suddenly due to battrey failure. After that I tried to updating which shows failure and told to configure dpkg.